# How to call An activity class from nonactivityclass (class without extends anything) in android?

Tags: android

I want call an activity class from a normal java class(without extends anything) for every some time interval to refresh the Ui, Is it possible to call an activity from normal java class. We can call the activity from another activity using intent and startactivity. But am not sure about calling the activity from class.

For example

```
 class example extends Activity
    {

    }
class example2 extends Activity
{
// we can call like
Intent intent = new Intent(this.example2,example.class);
startActivity(intent);
}

    class test
    {
// How can i call example or example2 from here.
    }
```

Thanks,

Lakshmanan

Answer (score 2):

You could provide a parameter consisting of the context of your Activity that has been creating the Object. Then you can use the Context's methods just like within an Activity.

i.g.

```
public class Foo {
  private Context context;

  public Foo(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  public void startActivity() {
   context.startActivity(/*your intent here*/);
  }
}
```

Comment: when i call context.startactivityforresult is give me error ? help me ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent12 = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), ImageClick.class);
context.startActivity(intent12);
```

It works. I've tried.

Answer (score -1):

I use this to view you tube videos from a non activity class -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // important step
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this helps you.

- Salil.

Comment: @ Salil this is fine for view url form non activity class. But i need to go to ActivityClass from non activity class.